# Can a Beit Midrash demand payment for carrying a smartphone?

Tags: halacha, synagogue, knas-penalty

I went to a certain Beis Midrash and saw a sign saying that anyone who enters with a smartphone has to donate money to the Beis Midrash as a penalty.

Is someone entering with such a phone really required to pay? What if the person only notices the sign when leaving? Does this fall under “al daas baal habayis? (complying to host's rules)”

Comment: I think you will get more answers if you generalize your question. I think your question is more of the overall form, "Can a shul enforce a (monetary) penalty for not following its rules?" E.g. one shul has a rule mentioned in its membership sign-up stating that any member engaging in hostile behavior towards another member will be banned from attending the shul and forfeit his membership dues.

Comment: I think your question needs to be clarified a bit. Are you asking whether a Shul can enforce an entry fee/rules? The answer I think is obviously yes. It sounds like you might be asking whether after the fact, if the policy wasn't clear, does one have to pay the fee. That might be a bit more complicated. But regardless, I think your question could be strongly improved by clarifying what you're asking.

Comment: What's this rule of "al daas baal habayis" that you reference? If a Baal habayis tells you to give him $500, you have to listen? What obligates you?

Comment: @Fei23 It is a good question which I +1'd. AlBerko and I tried to help by editing to depersonalized and get this question reopened. You can [edit] further if you like. But you might want to say more about the "al daas baal habayis" as not everyone might be familiar with this rule (I am not for instance)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96869/discussion-on-question-by-fei23-can-a-beit-midrash-demand-payment-for-carrying-a).

Comment: Perhaps this is really a question for your CLOR — and maybe even beis din if there is any dispute involved.